# Integer representation of textual value (as unique ID for query layer)

Tags: arcgis-pro, oracle-dbms, query-layer, unique-id, integer

I have an Oracle 18c non-spatial table that has textual IDs as the unique ID:

- The table doesn't have a ObjectID or numeric ID. I'm not able to add new columns to the table.
- The table isn't registered with a GDB.

> ```
> ID            
> --------------
> Bridge-100A
> Bridge-100B
> Bridge-100C
> Struct1
> Struct1-2
> Struct5-2a
> BR-King-1-East
> ```

---

I want to use the table in an ArcGIS Pro 2.9 **query layer.** So I need a unique ID column.

I could use Oracle's ROWNUM pseudocolumn as the unique ID:

```
cast(rownum as number(38,0)) as rownum
```

But I wonder if it would be better to use a real table column as the query layer's unique ID.

One option would be to use the textual column as-is, since I believe unique textual columns are supported by query layers.

But, I suspect it might be safer to represent the textual IDs as integers — via a calculated column in an SQL query. I suspect query layers work best with unique IDs that are *integers*, not text.

---

How can I convert the textual values to integers in a way that would be recognized by ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 0):

I think I can use the ORA_HASH() function to get the numeric hash.

```
select 
    ora_hash(id) id_hash
from 
    my_tbl

   ID_HASH
----------
 877186355
3699931891
 307189058
2638611691
4284978767
 176185254
 858279639
```

Oracle Help: [ORA_HASH](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/ORA_HASH.html)